# Regular expression which matches a function name and its parentheses only when there is content inside

Tags: javascript, regex

Inside of the parentheses there will be a web link which is a string between single quotes.

The name of the function will always be the same.

For example if I have `my_func('https://old.reddit.com')` the string `my_func(` and `)` should be matched and `'https://old.reddit.com'` should not.

The best thing I can come up with is `my_func\((?=[^\)]+)\)`.

Comment: Decide... JS or Python?

Comment: What's the context here? Why don't you use an actual _parser_ to get the information you're looking for?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Sorry, JS

Comment: You don't need lookahead here. Start with [`my_func\([^()]+\)`](https://regex101.com/r/kG0VSV/2).

Comment: As in the OP's own words ... _"[a] regular expression which matches a function name and its parentheses **only when there is content inside**"_ ... simply [`const regX = /my_func\('(.+?)'\)/`](https://regex101.com/r/q9UeMK/1) ... or ... [`const regX = /my_func\('(\S+)'\)/`](https://regex101.com/r/q9UeMK/2) ... which then can be used like ... `regX.test(myFunctionString)`

Answer (score 0):

You could use lookbehind and lookahead
and match anything that is not a quote (one or more times) until a closing quote and closed brace:

```js
const getFnArg = (str) => str.match(/(?<=\bmy_func\(['"`])[^'"`]+(?=['"`]\))/)?.[0];
console.log(getFnArg(`my_func('https://old.reddit.com')`))  // "https://old.reddit.com"
console.log(getFnArg(`my_func('whatever')`))  // "whatever"
console.log(getFnArg(`my_func(noquotes)`))    // undefined
console.log(getFnArg(`my_func('')`))          // undefined
console.log(getFnArg(`my_func()`))            // undefined
```

[Regex1010.com demo](https://regex101.com/r/JacoUL/2)

Or a simpler example without lookbehind/ahead:

```js
const getFnArg = (str) => str.match(/\bmy_func\(['"`]([^'"`]+)['"`]\)/)?.[1];
console.log(getFnArg(`my_func('https://old.reddit.com')`))  // "https://old.reddit.com"
console.log(getFnArg(`my_func('whatever')`))  // "whatever"
console.log(getFnArg(`my_func(noquotes)`))    // undefined
console.log(getFnArg(`my_func('')`))          // undefined
console.log(getFnArg(`my_func()`))            // undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.+?`.

```
my_func\(.+?\)
```

This will match your static text, and allow for any value within the opening and closing parentheses.

The `?` will modify the `+`, making it a lazy-quantifier.
This is in the case you have text with more than one `my_func` match, the balanced parenthesis will be matched, and not the adjacent match's.

Comment: You should use `[^()]` instead of `.`. Consider the following [demo](https://regex101.com/r/pi30zk/1)